# ImportError: No module named functools ( Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-import, functools

I am getting below error while running Python Batch in Win10 Python2.7. The same batch was previously running in Win7.

```
C:/Users/Chris/.platformio/penv/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 703, in 
main()
C:/Users/Chris/.platformio/penv/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 692, in main
aliasmbcs()
C:/Users/Chris/.platformio/penv/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 515, in aliasmbcs
import locale, codecs
C:\Users\Chris.platformio\penv\lib\python2.7/locale.py", line 17, in 
import functools

ImportError: No module named functools

checked Python27 has Functool installed.
```

Kindly help..!!

Comment: [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) is standard module and it should be preinstalled with Python. If it can't find it then something wrong with installed Python. Maybe you will have to reinstall Python.

Comment: Hello Furas. thanks ..Python is installed properly . the same batch was working in Win7 but now we have upgraded to Win10.. is there any other way to fix this issue ?

Comment: yes, you can reinstall Python because this module is installed with Python and you can't install it in other way. Maybe upgrading removed some important elements. Batch can be still OK but Python seems not OK.

Comment: Might be related: https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide/issues/1348

Comment: something seems to be messing around with the path separators there ("\" vs. "/"). Is that an issue?

Comment: @Mr.Fuppes : Path seems to be fine.. it's a typo mistacke.. please ignore...